# Can I make WordPress theme from html template designed by 3rd party?

Tags: wordpress, html

I am not a designer that's why I need to buy others template and then convert them to WordPress to sell in marketplace. I saw some awesome html templates I really love them and I didn't find these templates for WordPress. That's why I am willing to buy these html templates and convert them to WordPress theme.

Is it acceptable by themeforest and other marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can convert static HTML themes to Wordpress, but you would need some knowledge of Wordpress development to do so. It would entail replacing the content with the dynamic functions that Wordpress provides.

Buying themes from places like Themeforest is perfectly acceptable, and a great deal of small businesses and blogs do this. Just make sure the theme will do what you need it to. Also, worth checking their return policy - many premium themes and plugins have a 30-day money-back guarantee which will allow you to make sure the theme is right for you or you can get your money back, no questions asked.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I want to buy html template from themeforest or any other marketplace, then convert the template into wordpress, then sale the converted theme in themeforest. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Ah sorry I understand now. That would depend on the license I suppose, but generally I think that you would not be allowed without the authors permission. Your safest bet would be to contact the theme author and ask their explicit permission to do this. The issue is that most people would not like the fact that you are making money on something they've designed without taking a cut for themselves.